# Change location to call swagger-ui in Spring

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

How I can change location to call swagger api docs from `http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html` to `http://localhost:8081/my-api-doc`?

My SwaggerConfig is

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.package"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }
```

And I use `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui` both with `version 2.7.0`.

Comment: This works perfectly [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59948001/6629184)

Answer (score 0):

This is all I can did it.

```
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

            registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation/v2/api-docs", "/v2/api-docs?group=restful-api");
            registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation/swagger-resources/configuration/ui","/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
            registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation/swagger-resources/configuration/security","/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
            registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources");
            registry.addRedirectViewController("/documentation", "/documentation/swagger-ui.html");
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
             registry.
                     addResourceHandler("/documentation/swagger-ui.html**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html");
            registry.
                    addResourceHandler("/documentation/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
```

This methods is added in a configuration class that extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` like that 
`public class Configuration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {...}`

You can't remove `swagger-ui.html` or change because is hard-coded in source code.

Answer (score 0):

If using Spring Boot, you can add a mapping to redirect the request like:

```java
@GetMapping("/swagger")
public void swaggerRedirect(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Location", "/swagger-ui.html");
    response.setStatus(302);
}
```