# Changing OpenAPI's autogenerated HomeController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a Open API 3.0 swagger doc. I am using Spring's OpenAPI autogen plugin to generate the API controllers and Delegates.

There is a `HomeController` that gets autogenerated.

```
/**
 * Home redirection to OpenAPI api documentation
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "redirect:swagger-ui.html";
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can change base path in my swagger documentation to create a `HomeController` similar to this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "redirect:/rest/swagger-ui.html";
    }
}
```

My stack:

1. Spring Boot: 2.1.1
2. Openapi: 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Look at these:

- [Change location to call swagger-ui in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180375/change-location-to-call-swagger-ui-in-spring)
- [How to change swagger-ui.html default path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193286/how-to-change-swagger-ui-html-default-path)

My raw solution:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/rest
```

but in this way all the paths start whit /rest

**EDIT**

can this be fine?

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/rest")
    public String index() {
        return "redirect:/swagger-ui.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: I need different paths. The for /rest related resources and other resources which are /application related resources

Comment: as I said, that controller is autogenerated. I cannot change that specific class.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/5759