# Need to update swagger UI Path for spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am having a spring boot project and need to update my swagger path from

> http://localhost:9012/swagger-ui.html

to

> http://localhost:9012/myservice/swagger-ui.html

I am not using any context path for my application I have tried all the below approach but none of them worked.

[Change location to call swagger-ui in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180375/change-location-to-call-swagger-ui-in-spring)

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1443

[How to change swagger-ui.html default path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193286/how-to-change-swagger-ui-html-default-path)

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1080

[How to change Swagger-ui URL prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712519/how-to-change-swagger-ui-url-prefix)

```
private static final String PATH = "/myservice";

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    final String apiDocs = "/v2/api-docs";
    final String configUi = "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui";
    final String configSecurity = "/swagger-resources/configuration/security";
    final String resources = "/swagger-resources";
    final String swaggerUI = "/swagger-ui.html";

    registry.addRedirectViewController(apiDocs, PATH +apiDocs).setKeepQueryParams(true);
    registry.addRedirectViewController(resources, PATH +resources);
    registry.addRedirectViewController(configUi, PATH +configUi);
    registry.addRedirectViewController(configSecurity, PATH +configSecurity);
    registry.addRedirectViewController(swaggerUI, PATH + swaggerUI);
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/",PATH);
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
    registry.addResourceHandler(PATH + "/swagger-ui.html**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html");
    registry.addResourceHandler(PATH + "/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
  }
```

I am using swagger version 2.9.2
Is there any other way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi @Kashyap, can you check https://howtodoinjava.com/swagger2/swagger-spring-mvc-rest-example/

Comment: Try adding a context path `server.servlet.contextPath=/myservice` in your application.properties and see if it works.

Comment: Hi LUC1F3R and Sudoss, both the ways suggest adding context path if I add context path to my application all the other APIs URLs will also change which I don't want.

Comment: @Kashyap got it...looks like redirect/forward is what you are looking for. Please try the code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63028959/8938332) and let us know if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this redirect method in your controller, I have tested it and it works

```
@RequestMapping("/myservice/swagger-ui.html")
public String redirectToSwagger() {
    return "redirect:/swagger-ui.html";
}
```

You can use either of redirect or forward based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following swagger dependency. All you have to do is just add in the pom.xml, it will work like charm. Remove any swagger related annotation like `@EnableSwagger2`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Swagger URL: ***http://{base_url}/swagger-ui/index.html***

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code it requires `@Controller` not a `@RestController`

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import springfox.documentation.annotations.ApiIgnore;

@Controller
@ApiIgnore
public class SwaggerMappingController {

    @RequestMapping("/swagger-ui.html")
    public String greeting() {
        return "redirect:/swagger-ui/index.html";
    }
}
```